# Textbox validate event in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I’m new in asp.net. and I’m am creating a simple Shoe Store Billing Management System. I want to know how to fire textbox validate event. Just like as we do in windows app textbox validate event. I have lost of shoes in my shoes table. And there is two column in table ShoseCode and ShoseDesc. When I enter the ShoseCode in txt_ShoseCode and if this ShoseCode is already exist in ShoseCode Column. So this txt_ShoseCode retrieve information from database. Or if this cant retrieve so just show the message like “This Shoes Code already exist” or something like this.

And I'm using asp:Panel (ModalPopupExtender). Because of AutoPostBack="True" in txt_ShoseCode the value is remove in txt_ShoseCode when I fire txt_ShoseCode_TextChanged event. And I also don't know how to use javascript or jquery for this.

Thanks in Advance

'

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Display(ShoseCode) {
            alert(ShoseCode + ':::ShoseCode');
            if (alert) {
                window.location = 'WebForm1.aspx';
            }
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
        <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Labelcheck"  
            Text="Please enter any ShoseCode to be verified from the database" 
            runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF99" 
        Width="197px" ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_ShoseCode" runat="server" Width="197px" 
            AutoPostBack="True" ontextchanged="txt_ShoseCode_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="txt_ShoseCode" ErrorMessage="*ShoseCode Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <br />
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server"  Interval="10000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
               </asp:Timer>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" BackColor="#FF3300" 
        ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

'

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand com;
        string str;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void ShoseCode_check()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            con.Open();
            str = "select count(*)from tblShoes where ShoesCode ='" + txt_ShoseCode.Text + "'";
            com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());
            if (count > 0)
            {

                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ShowSuccess", "javascript:Display('" + txt_ShoseCode.Text + "')", true);
                lblMessage.Text = "This Shoes Code already exist";
            }
            else
            {

                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ShowSuccess", "javascript:Display('" + txt_ShoseCode.Text + "')", true);
                lblMessage.Text = "This Shoes Code does not exist";
            }

        }

        protected void txt_ShoseCode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShoseCode_check();
        }

        protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding some of your code and markup, please. also showing us what you've tried might help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `onblur` event of text box using `jQuery` .

Comment: This should be a comment dude.

Answer (score 0):

As i said in your other question that and someone also mentioned here that you can use **onblur** event of text box using **jQuery**

So remove the event - ***ontextchanged="txt_ShoseCode_TextChanged"*** and ***AutoPostBack="True"*** from your textbox. so now it look like this -

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_ShoseCode" runat="server" Width="197px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Now As you said in the question that -

> When I enter the ShoseCode in txt_ShoseCode and if this ShoseCode is
>   already exist in ShoseCode Column. So this txt_ShoseCode retrieve
>   information from database. Or if this cant retrieve so just show the
>   message like “This Shoes Code already exist” or something like this.

To achieve this functionality how you can use Jquery with "blur" event is as below.

First attach blur event to your textbox.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#<%=txt_ShoseCode.ClientID %>').blur(ShowAvailability);
});
```

Here **ShowAvailability()** is a javascript function which calls server side method using page method and jquery ajax like this-

```
function ShowAvailability() {    
    $('#<%=Label1.ClientID %>').removeAttr("style");
    $('#<%=Label1.ClientID %>').html('Please wait...');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebForm1.aspx/CheckShoseCodeAvailability",
        data: "{'shoseCode':'" + $('#<%=txt_ShoseCode.ClientID %>').val() + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            $('#<%=Label1.ClientID %>').html('');
            switch (response.d) {
                case "1":
                    $('#<%=Label1.ClientID %>').html('This Shoes Code does not exist');
                case "2":
                    $('#<%=Label1.ClientID %>').html('This Shoes Code already exist');
        },
        error: function () {
              alert("An error has occurred during processing your request.");
         }
    }); 
}
```

and here is the page method - **CheckShoseCodeAvailability()**

```
[WebMethod()]
 public static string CheckShoseCodeAvailability(string shoseCode)
 {
            string availStatus = string.Empty;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            con.Open();
            str = "select count(*) from tblShoes where ShoesCode ='" + shoseCode + "'";
            com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());
            con.Close();
            if (count > 0)
                 availStatus = "2";
            else
               availStatus = "1";

            return availStatus;
  }
```

I put the code without any testing. So first verify from your end. That's it. Hope you now get it

**Note:**  *It seems you are desktop application developer. But let me tell you one thing - Stackoverflow site is not for spoon feeding to developer. First you have to try at your self, googled it and still if you not get any idea then and then post your doubt here in SO. In this question you got -2 votes because without any try you directly post question. There are lots of sites and blogs available to learn asp.net and jquery. Hope you now get it what i want to say...*